# Fastlane How to automate the deletion of provisioning profile?

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, fastlane

I'm in a situation where I need to automate the deletion of appstore provision profiles.
I tried to `fastlane match nuke distribution` but it revoked certificated to and I just want to remove provisioning profile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this script can do it you need to pass TeamID and bundellID

```
lane :delete_profiles do |options|
    require "spaceship" 
    ENV['FASTLANE_TEAM_ID'] = options[:team_id]
    Spaceship::Portal.select_team
    matching_profiles = Spaceship::Portal.provisioning_profile.app_store.find_by_bundle_id(bundle_id: options[:bundle_id])
    Spaceship::Portal.client.delete_provisioning_profile!(matching_profiles.first.id)
  end
```

> fastlane delete_profiles bundle_id:'YourBundelID'
>   team_id:'YourTeamId'

As my Apple ID is added to multiple teams so I just select the team first.
Then get the provisioning profile by ID then delete it.

Comment: Before being able to call `Spaceship::Portal.select_team` I needed to call `Spaceship.login` otherwise I would get the error `undefined method select_team for nil:NilClass`